# Unreal Engine 4 - Text Renders

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am basicly making a system to show texts like "E to Open" when player getting close to a chest or door. I use this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQaYI.jpg

When I hit first chest, everything's fine but second or any other text won't show after that.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I think your question rather suits the gamedev exchange.

Comment: Hey man, I'm sorry if it's wrong place. I just signed up to the website. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is what you meant?

Comment: Exactly. You can ask questions there speciffically related to game development process while stackoverflow is more suitable for all your programming  problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help.